# CSS Grid full width mobile, center desktop without Media Queries

Tags: css, css-grid

I am trying to play around with CSS grid. I am hoping for desktop to have white space on left and right but in mobile, it should take up the whole screen.

I know I can do this with media queries. How I can make the same layout in CSS grid without using media queries?

Here is a Codepen with the code I have so far.

https://codepen.io/jrock2004/pen/vdqgMg

Here is the CSS code

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 768px 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas:
        ". header ."
        ". main ."
        ". footer .";
}
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Ok, I figured it out.

grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(100px, 700px) 1fr;

Comment: This is a crazy hack. Good thinking.

Comment: Please answer your question for future users